# Symbolism/figure of speech for honor or equivalent

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, word-usage

Not sure if I'm posting in the correct stack; my apologies in advance if it's not:

In medieval times (low/mid/high), what would be the equivalent to a figure of speech for something like "my word is my badge of honor" ?

Many thanks

Comment: [In the history of Europe, the Middle Ages (or Medieval Period) lasted from the 5th to the 15th century.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages) Chaucer just about squeezes in at the tail end, but even he would be incomprehensible to non-specialist Anglophones today.  That's to say you wouldn't understand any such "medieval equivalent" even if someone here could come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

According to Victoria S. Dennis [here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/56/messages/430.html):

> : What is the origin of the term "My word is my bond" and who was the author?
>
> It doesn't have an author. In this specific form it has for centuries been the motto of the London Stock Exchange, but in various forms (e.g. "a gentleman's/Englishman's word is as good as his bond") it goes back at least to 1500, when a Scottish source has ""O kingis word shuld be o kingis bonde".